# How to use model class of a classifer prepared using weka in eclipse

Tags: java, weka

I have created a classifier in weka using GUI, I saved the classifier and the result was a .model file, I want to use this classifier in my java project in eclipse.

I read [this](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/language-identification-as-text.html) blog, it says that I will require a model.dat file to do this, but how can I get the model.dat file from model file?

Answer (score 0):

The `.dat` in `model.dat` is just an extension that the author used for his files.  Here's a reference for [how to load your model](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Saving+and+loading+models).  Here's another article for [loading a model in Java](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization).